# Import .txt in r : issue with accents in italian language

Tags: r

I' am trying to import a txt file (an italian lexicon for sentiment analysis) but when imported in r the accented characters aren't in the correct form.
For example `à` becomes `ä`.
I use r studio and i've tried different encoding but none works.

thank you

This is my sessioninfo():

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

This is the link of the txt file:
https://github.com/gragusa/sentiment-lang-italian

Comment: You probably need to describe your setup in more detail and post the results of `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: > Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252"

Comment: And   ...setup details?

Comment: Sorry i'm a newbie...how can i show them to you?

Comment: The most efficient way is to execute `sessionInfo()` and paste the beginning potions into your question with SO [edit] facilities. We can tell you are on Windoze from the 1252 code page, but we cannot tell which flavor or which version of R. It also might be helpful to paste in the top of what you see when you open the file with a text editor.

Comment: Done what you suggested to me. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: I wrote BEGINNING   ... i.e.. the part that has your OS and R version numbers. And you need to find a text teditor that does a better job of displaying non-ASCII characters, ... something like Sublime3.

Comment: Updated. Thank you